# I have a data in python like below in a variable.But i want to be in int list but not like string.how to convert it?

Tags: python-2.7

```
a="[['212131', '21331', '21323', '113312'], ['21212', '1212', '12211', '212112'], ['1234', '435678', '766576', '7'], ['1222', '2121', '21221', '213131']]"
```

I have this string type list. How to convert into normal list so that it will give `a[0][0]='212131'`.

Comment: `a` itself is also a string?

Comment: yes a itself is a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title of your question hints that you want integers in the end.

So, combine `ast.literal_eval` which evaluates your string into a list of lists of strings with a list comprehension to convert strings to integers and rebuild the list of lists as lists of integers.

```
import ast

a = "[['212131', '21331', '21323', '113312'], ['21212', '1212', '12211', '212112'], ['1234', '435678', '766576', '7'], ['1222', '2121', '21221', '213131']]"
# mutate a into the proper type
a = [[int(x) for x in sl] for sl in ast.literal_eval(a)]

print(a)
```

result:

```
[[212131, 21331, 21323, 113312], [21212, 1212, 12211, 212112], [1234, 435678, 766576, 7], [1222, 2121, 21221, 213131]]
```

and (as expected):

```
>>> a[0][0]
212131
```

Note that if you want `a[0][0]='212131'` as string, `a = ast.literal_eval(a)` is enough and there's not much to answer to...